# How to determine whether MediaElement is playing?

Tags: wpf

I want to determine video is_playing on my player .
But how??
Please help me.
I am using c#>w_pf .net framework 4.5.1
I want to create a event like this video.

[See Photo Demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4E6MbGGj8OdbGJTQURqWXl3VzQ)

I want to control play/pause button like that player.
How can I control play/pause button image change while video is playing.
Please help me

Comment: If the player is a proper WPF control, just bind to the property that indicates the playing state or register a handler to player related events. You linked demo is blocked by the proxy at my place and you don't provide any information about your "player", so I don't know how you expect help

Answer (score 0):

i did this by having 2 buttons and binding the visibility of those buttons to a bool that you control when your buttons are clicked.

basically you must keep track of the play pause state yourself. media element wont do this for you.

in main window xaml add the following:

```
// Two converters used with the visibility binding
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <local:InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources> 

// Need to make sure we add loaded behaviour or it will crash app
<MediaElement Name="mePlayer" 
                  LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
                  Source="C:\Users\SamG\Downloads\ZW_20160102_064536A.avi"/>


<Button Content="Play" Name="Play" Click="Play_OnClick" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=IsPaused, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<Button Content="Pause" Name="Pause" Click="Pause_OnClick" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=IsPaused, Converter={StaticResource InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Inverted}"/>
```

you must also name this window make sure you put this inside

```
x:Name="mainWindow"
```

in the c# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isPaused;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mePlayer.Play();
        IsPaused = true;
    }

    private void Play_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mePlayer.Play();

        IsPaused = false;
    }

    private void Pause_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mePlayer.Pause();

        IsPaused = true;
    }

    public bool IsPaused
    {
        get { return _isPaused; }
        set
        {
            _isPaused = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

then add a new class called InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class InvertableBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    enum Parameters
    {
        Normal, Inverted
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolValue = (bool) value;
        var direction = (Parameters) Enum.Parse(typeof (Parameters), (string) parameter);

        if (direction == Parameters.Inverted)
            return !boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

        return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

copy this code it should work for what you need

Comment: **Hey**..........
**Its not working**




`if (mePlayer.SpeedRatio == 0)//Pause
            {
                Play.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Pause.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else if(mePlayer.SpeedRatio == 1)//Playing
            {
                Play.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Pause.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }`

Comment: can you show me all of your code, what you are working with.

Comment: **Not working brother**

`public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (mePlayer.SpeedRatio == 0)//Pause
            {

                Play.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Pause.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else if(mePlayer.SpeedRatio == 1)//Playing
            {
                Play.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                Pause.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
}`

Comment: my bad. the speed ratio wont work in this way, see edits for the answer

Comment: Sam Brother

Please give me your project:

Comment: I have hosted it on git hub. click the clone or download button and download the zip to get the project in a zip file.
https://github.com/sgreaves1/playpausetest